# Should I also flag questions when I already voted to close?

Tags: support, flagging, vote-to-close

I wonder whether I should also flag questions on which I've already voted for a close. Should they still be flagged so the mods can see it or should the community just manage itself?

98% of the questions I vote to close on lead to a close sooner or later anyway. Many times those questions are clearly off-topic or non-constructive and in my opinion they should not get any answers at all, so it's probably the best thing to flag them, too, in order to have them closed as soon as possible. But I wonder whether such flags are mere noise for the moderators and whether it's acceptable to wait until the community closes the question by itself.

Please note that I do not vote to close on questions which should just be migrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general "no" flagging and closing isn't normally necessary.

However, if it's a question that you think won't get seen by many more users with the right to vote to close then flagging is an option.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an existing migration path, you should vote to close and pick it. Otherwise, yeah, flagging is more appropriate.

In addition to what ChrisF said, I periodically check the list of questions that are gathering close votes. So even if a question doesn't get flagged, odds are I'll see it anyway and might take some action on it.